# Haproxy Load Balance IMAP,POP3,SMTP: Unable to use proxy 'imap' with wrong mode, required: http, has: tcp

Tags: smtp, haproxy, docker, imap, pop3

I try to reverse proxy all the incoming email traffic to a
 [mailcow-dockerized](https://mailcow.email/) solution in my debian server via haproxy:

The `haproxy.cfg` configuration is:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


frontnend smtp
   bind *:25
   default_backend smtp_public

frontend submission
  bind *:587
  default_backend smtp_submission

frontend smtp_ssl
   bind *:449
   default_backend smtp_ssl

frontend pop3
  bind *:995
  default_backend pop3_

frontend imap
  bind *:993
  default_backend imap

backend smtp_public 
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   server docker 127.0.0.1:2525 check

backend smtp_ssl
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   server docker 127.0.0.1:2465

backend smtp_submission
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   server docker 127.0.0.1:2587

backend pop3_
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   server docker 127.0.0.1:2995

backend imap
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   server docker 127.0.0.1:2993
```

And the images running are:

```
ec79939443d4        mailcow/acme:1.3        "/srv/docker-entry..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours                                                           
29c295d44767        mailcow/rspamd:1.1      "/docker-entrypoin..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours                                                           
2d09fd009c39        nginx:mainline-alpine   "/bin/sh -c 'envsu..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours (healthy)   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                
a00d9477c464        mailcow/fail2ban:1.0    "python2 -u /logwa..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours                                                           
6fdf54789459        mailcow/phpfpm:1.0      "/docker-entrypoin..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours             9000/tcp                                      
091d621123aa        mailcow/sogo:1.0        "/bin/sh -c 'exec ..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours                                                           
1028c60923a0        redis:alpine            "docker-entrypoint..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours             6379/tcp                                      
827c20cee898        mailcow/dovecot:1.0     "/docker-entrypoin..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours             24/tcp, 10001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2110->110/tcp, 0.0.
76a977a8064e        mailcow/postfix:1.0     "/bin/sh -c 'exec ..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours             588/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2525->25/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2465->4
2299076f475f        memcached:alpine        "docker-entrypoint..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours             11211/tcp                                     
03b56dcc1563        mailcow/unbound:1.0     "/docker-entrypoin..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours (healthy)   53/tcp, 53/udp                                
21f5a3673f3f        mariadb:10.1            "docker-entrypoint..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours (healthy)   3306/tcp                                      
e2af96428a94        robbertkl/ipv6nat       "/docker-ipv6nat -..."   46 hours ago        Up 46 hours                                                           
97fcf9ad82ad        mailcow/clamd:1.0       "/bootstrap.sh"          46 hours ago        Up 46 hours             3310/tcp
```

But I get the following error:

```
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver haproxy[58310]: [ALERT] 184/172851 (58310) : Unable to use proxy 'imap' with wrong mode, required: http, has: tcp.
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver haproxy[58310]: [ALERT] 184/172851 (58310) : You may want to use 'mode http'.
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver haproxy[58310]: [ALERT] 184/172851 (58310) : Proxy 'imap': unable to find required default_backend: 'imap'.
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver haproxy[58310]: [ALERT] 184/172851 (58310) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver systemd[1]: haproxy.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver systemd[1]: Stopping HAProxy Load Balancer...
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver systemd[1]: haproxy.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
Ιούλ 04 17:28:51 DockerMailserver systemd[1]: Unit haproxy.service entered failed state.
```

Do you fellows have an idea how to fix the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, `mode` can be set on all sections (`backend`, `frontend`, `defaults`, `listen`). You have a `defaults` section `mode http`. Could this be applying to the `frontend` sections that don't have mode specified?

Try specifying `mode tcp` for the frontends that are using backends with `mode tcp`.